# Generate a JSON schema from POJO array using Jackson

Tags: java, arrays, json, jackson, jsonschema

I want to generate a JSON schema from POJO array using Jackson 2.7.0:

```
JsonSchema schema = mapper.generateJsonSchema(MyClass[].class);
```

So I expect to get JSON schema:

```
{
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "text": {
        "type": "string"
      }
  ...
```

But get:

```
{
      "type": "array"
}
```

How get expected schema?
Does exist any better library to generate a schema from POJO?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 9):

`JsonSchema` is deprecated since version `2.2`,
If you are using gradle or maven use [`jackson-module-jsonSchema`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jsonSchema) as dependency

```
compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jsonSchema:2.9.0
```

And then you can create your schema in this way :

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

JsonSchemaGenerator schemaGen = new JsonSchemaGenerator(mapper);
JsonSchema schema = schemaGen.generateSchema(MyClass[].class);

String schemaText = mapper.writeValueAsString(schema);
```

This will work for you

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helps.

Answer (score -2):

```
//Using below code you can custom json schema
public static String getJsonSchema(Class clazz) throws IOException {
         Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();

         List<Map<String,String>> map=new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
         for (Field field : fields) {
             HashMap<String, String> objMap=new  HashMap<String, String>();
             objMap.put("name", field.getName());
             objMap.put("type", field.getType().getSimpleName());
             objMap.put("format", "");
             map.add(objMap);
         }
         ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
         String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(map);

       return json;
    }
```